# Custom Toolbar Back Button Attribute

Tags: java, android

[image]

I have a custom toolbar which is in the image. In some activities, I will use the same toolbar but navigation icon will be back icon.

I actually did it. But when I remove `ImageView(navigationicon)` and set `back button`;

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Normally toolbar width sizes mix. But I also want to use back button with parentActivity attribute. What is the easiest way to handle this (I use API 21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NB:I am using a collapsing toolbar as an example.**
In your onCreate,after declaring your custom toolbar and its layout as follows:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
            findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitleEnabled(true);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Profile");
    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Set a parent activity in your manifest.And you will get a back arrow in your tool bar that returns to the previous activity or whatever your parent activity is;As follows:

```
 <activity
        android:name="SecondActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="MainActivity"/>
```

Additionaly,you can also set the target API in your manifest as follows:

```
<activity
        android:name="SecondActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="MainActivity"
        tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />
```

In your situation:Your target API will be Lollipop(21)

Comment: Thanks for help. My title is very thin and I also need to use thin back button which is not available in vector asset. If I use an imageview as back button (256x256) does it occur a graphical problem? In my Note4 seems no problem as visual.

Comment: Create a custom back button in your vector assets using the default create vector..Then you can customize the back button in your xml.And if you are using an imageview,simply upload it as a toolbar icon,Android Studio will resize the imageview for you according to the developer recommended sizes for toolbar assets.

Answer (score 2):

Use fallowing code for back button in toolbar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_icon);// Toolbar icon in Drawable folder
    toolbar.setTitle("App");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);// Title Color
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();// Do what do you want on toolbar button
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

*try this you can change the icon in every activity and funtionality either *

```
  Toolbar t = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionToolbar(t);
        t.setNavigationIcon(icon);
        t..setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  @Override  public void onClick(View v) { // do what you want here  } });
```